# make checkboxes instead of already checked list

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, listview

I have a problem in this code. It is working and giving me IP addresses already checked. I want to put checkboxes which I can choose from one or more than one IP address. Look at the image under the code below: enter image description

```
btnScan = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scan);
listViewIp = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listviewip);


ipList = new ArrayList();
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, android.R.id.text1, ipList);
listViewIp.setAdapter(adapter);

btnScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new ScanIpTask().execute();
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: checkout https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox

Comment: Are you saying you want have the ability to select more than one item on the list and onClick() perform a task?

Comment: @ThabisoMotswagole i dont have the ability to check any thing the ip addresses after scan button shown with already checked.i want checkbox appear instead of this already check see the image under the code

Comment: `i dont have the ability to check any thing` ?? you mean "to uncheck anything"?

Comment: You are building up the listview/recycleview yourself i think. So why are you doing it as you do now?

Comment: Ok so you want the button to appear only after you have selected an IP address... correct?

Comment: yes i cant uncheck, i want to have the ability of check and unckeck any ip address i got after scan

Comment: @ThabisoMotswagole i want an empty check box appear beside every ip address after scan, and i can have the ability to choose the ip address by mark the check box beside the ip to get this ip device disconnected of connection on wifi

Comment: @ThabisoMotswagole thanks for your helping, but i still have error with adapterview

Answer (score 0):

This will stop the button from being clickable before you can select an item and only allow button click after item is selected

```
btnScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan);
listViewIp = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewip);

btnScan.setEnabled(false);

ipList = new ArrayList();
adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this,
  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, android.R.id.text1, ipList);
listViewIp.setAdapter(adapter);

listViewIp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView << ? > adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
    btnScan.setEnabled(true);
    CheckBox yourCB = findViewById(R.id.yourCB);
    yourCB.setClickable(false);
  }
  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView << ? > adapterView) {

  }
});

btnScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    new ScanIpTask().execute();
  }
});
```

EDIT:
After reviewing your replies in the comments and your code you will need to use

```
parent.getItemAtPosition(position).getId()
```

Which will allow you to get the selected item.

Comment: sorry im new developer and this is a project for university, please tell me why adapterView in red color?

Comment: @SAAB it does that from time to time... put your cursor over the red underlined class and press and hold "ctrl" and "space"... then implement the methods

Comment: where i put this code?    parent.getItemAtPosition(position).getId()